# Counter part in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml

```
data Seq a = Nil | Cons a (Seq (a,a))
```

Ok, so this is a piece of haskell declaring a nested datatype of a binary tree,

yet is there a counter part in OCaml?

Show us in OCaml code if yes.

I have tried, but I wanna make sure if this is the same idea with the above:

```
type tree = Leaf of int | Node of int * tree * tree;; 

let l = Leaf 3;; 

let a = Node (1, l, l);; 

let a = Node (1, a, l);; 

let a = Node (1, a, l);; 

let a = Node (1, a, l);; 

let a = Node (1, a, l);; 

let rec value tree = match tree with 
| Leaf x -> x 
| Node (v, x, y) -> v + (value x) + (value y);; 

let rec len tree = match tree with 
| Leaf x -> 1 
| Node (v, x, y) -> 1 + (len x) + (len y);; 

value a;; 
len a;; 



# #use 
"1.ml";; 
type tree = Leaf of int | Node of int * tree * tree 
val l : tree = Leaf 3 
val a : tree = Node (1, Leaf 3, Leaf 3) 
val a : tree = Node (1, Node (1, Leaf 3, Leaf 3), Leaf 3) 
val a : tree = Node (1, Node (1, Node (1, Leaf 3, Leaf 3), Leaf 3), Leaf 3) 
val a : tree = 
Node (1, Node (1, Node (1, Node (1, Leaf 3, Leaf 3), Leaf 3), Leaf 3), 
Leaf 3) 
val a : tree = 
Node (1, 
Node (1, Node (1, Node (1, Node (1, Leaf 3, Leaf 3), Leaf 3), Leaf 3), 
Leaf 3), 
Leaf 3) 
val value : tree -> int = <fun> 
val len : tree -> int = <fun> 
- : int = 23 
- : int = 11
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can translate it quite literally:

```
type 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * ('a * 'a) seq
```

Here is a sample usage:

```
let s = Cons(1, Cons((1,2), Nil))   (* s : int seq *)
```

Comment: I think that his way of defining the tree type is more Camly than this one though don't you think ?

Comment: @double_squeeze, I'm not sure what you mean. It's neither more nor less Camly, it's simply a completely different type.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your definition of "completely different", because there is a bijection between them.

Comment: @double_squeeze, there is no bijection. For example, `Cons("s", Nil)` cannot be translated to `tree`. Conversely, and more interestingly, the tree `Node(1, Leaf 2, Node(3, Leaf 4, Leaf 5))` has no representation as `seq` because it is unbalanced -- enforcing balancing is the purpose of the `seq` type.

Answer (score 13):

The equivalent in OCaml is the following:

```
type 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * ('a * 'a) seq
```